# Nginx: Limit number of simultaneous connections per IP to backend

Tags: nginx

We use nginx with an application server as a backend.

We need to limit number of simultaneous connections per IP to backend. We used `limit_conn` nginx directive for this purpose. But it doesn't work well in all cases. 
If user generates a lot of connections from one IP and quickly closes them, then nginx passes this request to a backend, but because client connection is already closed, this connection is not count in `limit_conn`.

Is it possible to limit number of simultaneous connections per IP to backend server with nginx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to set

```
proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
```

> Determines should the connection with a proxied server be closed if a
>   client closes a connection without waiting for a response.

from the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort)

Another suggestion is to use `limit_req` to limit the request rate.

Comment: Nginx dev team suggests to use `proxy_ignore_client_abort off` also. It works so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this facility is not yet available for nginx out of the box. According to the [Nginx FAQ](http://wiki.nginx.org/Faq#What_algorithm_does_Nginx_use_to_load_balance.3F_Can_it_balance_based_on_connection_load.3F)

> Many users have requested that Nginx implement a feature in the load
>   balancer to limit the number of requests per backend (usually to one).
>   While support for this is planned, it's worth mentioning that demand
>   for this feature is rooted in misbehaviour on the part of the
>   application being proxied

I've seen some 3rd parties module for that [nginx-limit-upstream](https://github.com/cfsego/nginx-limit-upstream) but I've never tried.